# SQL Server 2008 Perform a draw between 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables on `SQL Server 2008`, each one has a single column and the same rows count number:

```
USERS               OPERATION

Name                Operation
-----------         -----------
John                W383
William             R823  
Karen               X933
Peter               M954
Alex                S744
```

I need to perform every week a random draw between the 2 tables to get something like the follow and save it into a 3rd. table:

`DRAW_RESULT`:

```
Name          Operation_Assigned  Week_Number
----------------------------------------------
Peter         M954                2
William       W383                2
John          S744                2
Alex          X933                2
Karen         R823                2

Name          Operation_Assigned  Week_Number
----------------------------------------------
William       R823                3
Alex          M954                3
Karen         X933                3
John          S744                3
Peter         W383                3
```

How can I do this using `T-SQL`?

Comment: What do you mean by a "draw"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're doing, something like this should work:

```
select name, operation from (
  select
    row_number() over (order by (select null)) as RN,
    name
  from
    users
) U join (
  select
    row_number() over (order by newid()) as RN,
    operation
  from
    operation
) O on U.RN = O.RN
```

Edit: row_number with newid() works, so removed the extra derived table.

Here's also [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67e68/1) to test this.

Comment: If the week number is just the current week, you can get that with datepart